# How to add "and" search operators to odoo XML-RPC api calls?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

I have a search statement that is the following

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,'stock.move', 'search_read',                                                                 [[['origin','=','INVOICE ## 44'],
['picking_type_id', '=', 2],
['product_id', '=', 123],
['state', '=', 'cancel']]],
)
```

I would like to be able to search for records that are cancelled AND assigned. I have attempted the following.

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,'stock.move', 'search_read',                                                                 [[['origin','=','INVOICE ## 44'],
    ['picking_type_id', '=', 2],
    ['product_id', '=', 123],
    ['|', ['state', '=', "cancel"], ['state', '=', "assigned"]]]
    )
```

However, this returns an error of the list not being a proper operator. I have checked the documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html and while they have examples, they do not have a clear explanation of how to implement for multiple of the same states or other attributes.

Comment: The brackets surrounding the `|` must be removed

Comment: That was it! Thank you! It was a silly syntax issue this whole time

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having similar issues, Kenly above was able to solve it, was a syntax issue. I was not able to find a clear example of this anywhere online, so posting here in case anyone finds a similar issue.

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
'stock.picking', 'search_read',
[['|', ['state', '=', "cancel"], ['state', '=', "assigned"]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   //query 
            inParams.push([
                ['id', 'in', location_ids], // AND
                ['service_id', '=', type],   // AND
                ['subscription_community', '!=', false],  // AND
                '|',   // OR
                ['nbplace', '=', nbplace1],
                ['nbplace', '=', nbplace2]
            ]);
            inParams.push(['id', 'car_ids']); //  projection  fileld
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to check the multi state of the record, we can simply use the `in` operator.

Try with this,

```
[['state', 'in', ["cancel", "assigned"]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can find under your own link on following [part](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#search-domains):

> Domain criteria can be combined using logical operators in prefix
> form:
>
> `'&'` logical AND, default operation to combine criteria following one
> another. Arity 2 (uses the next 2 criteria or combinations).
>
> `'|'` logical OR, arity 2.
>
> `'!'` logical NOT, arity 1.

So for your example you could either remove `|` (OR) Operator, because AND is default and must not be set. Or you can replace `|` with `&` if you find that more readable.